# Impossible to html_entity_decode the button title in a render array

Tags: forms

Here is the code that reside in my extended class of the `RegisterForm`:

```
$title=$this->t("M'inscrire") // notice the apostrophe in French
// the $element variable is the action sub array of the form
$element['submit']['#value'] = html_entity_decode($title, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
dpm(html_entity_decode($title, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

Unfortunately, my submit button is displayed like `M&#039inscrire`
And strangely, the dpm function print it as it should be

Edit to add, the following does not work:

```
$element['submit']['#value'] = $this->t("M'inscrire"); //NOT WORKING
$element['submit']['#value'] = "M'inscrire"; //NOT WORKING
```

Comment: You don't need to decode/encode the value. Drupal will handle that. Just `$element['submit']['#value'] = $this->t("M'inscrire")`.

Comment: @Jaypan many thanks, but unfortunately I still get `M&#039inscrire` if I use `$element['submit']['#value'] = $this->t("M'inscrire")` (This is why I have tried `html_entity_decode`

Comment: That is not standard Drupal behavior, so it means you've got something else in your system causing this problem. I'm guessing it's something in a template that is causing double-encoding.

Comment: Can you replicate on a fresh D8 install?

Comment: @Jaypan : you are completely right=> it was a bug in the template of the bootstrap_barrio theme. I have posted a patch for it: https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_barrio/issues/3083728#comment-13527917

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [Jaypan](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/66659/jaypan), it was due to a bug in the bootstrap_barrio theme.

I have posted a patch for it: https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_barrio/issues/3083728#comment-13527917